# How to manage a task queue using APScheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I would like to use APScheduler to handle task scheduling and queues.
I am currently using the very basic APScheduler settings: `BackgroundScheduler()`
I know how to start the scheduler and set some cron on interval trigger job.
But I can't figure out how to handle a proper queue.

Here is my code:

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

def test():
    print("Hello World !")

def start_job():
    scheduler.add_job(
        test
    )

start_job() # first task
start_job() # second task
start_job() # third task

scheduler.start()
```

This code kind of works but I need my tasks to run one after one and not all at the same time.

I've tried using the `max_instances` attribute but it doesn't change anything.

I've also tried to add an `id` to my job and then only the first task is started but not the left ones giving these warning:
`Execution of job "test (trigger: date[2021-01-12 17:55:48 UTC], next run at: 2021-01-12 17:55:48 UTC)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)`

How am I supposed to start the left tasks ?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am struggling with the same problem. I want to schedule multiple jobs, but none of them should overlap. If one is running then other should wait in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The executor you choose determines how the jobs are executed – whether in parallel or in a sequence. If you don't want any parallelism, you can use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `max_workers=1` to run them.

Comment: So I am currently making some test and I understand what you mean.
But when I reach the maximum number of workers occupied I have this warning:
`Run time of job "<lambda> (trigger: date[2021-01-20 16:36:40 UTC], next run at: 2021-01-20 16:36:40 UTC)" was missed by 0:00:10.003808`
And even after all workers are finished, the left jobs are not processed.
What am I missing ?

Comment: If you intend to use apscheduler as a task queue, you should disable the job deadline checking by setting `misfire_grace_time=None`. But then again, wouldn't it be easier to directly use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) or something?

Comment: So you meant the using the Python ThreadPoolExecutor, not [the one provided by APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/executors/pool.html#apscheduler.executors.pool.ThreadPoolExecutor) ?